# Bootstrap using image indead of glyphicon

Tags: java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, web, themes

Is it possible to use image inside bootstrap-min.css

We are using a theme (modern) and some icons are controlled by bootstrap.

I would like to change the following line to use image.

```
.glyphicon-home:before{content:"\e021"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.glyphicon-home{
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:url('../images/YOUR_IMAGE.png');
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Comment: Hello, Zealander, I tried to do like your comment, but without success.

Comment: In bootstrap-min: glyphicon-home:before{display:inline-block;background-image:url('http://clubee.com.br/teste/Source/admin1/assets/images/home.png');width:20px;height:20px}

Comment: on bootstrap.css: .glyphicon-home:before {
  /*content: "\e021";*/
  display:inline-block;
  background-image:url('http://clubee.com.br/teste/Source/admin1/assets/images/home.png');
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}

Comment: remove `:before`. Here's working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/4u50rk81/ I put a red border since I don't have an image. Also make sure the background image has correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the content parameter and add your own image using background.  The rest of the styles (display:inline-block) should still inherit.

```
.glyphicon-home:before{
    content: "";
    background: url(IMAGEPATH) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

Oh - and I wouldn't put it into bootstrap.min.css - add it to a stylesheet that is called later, or your theme's style.css